# Java recursive DFS knapsack stackoverflow with very large input, better way to pass lists in

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, depth-first-search, knapsack-problem

Implemented a recursive depth-first-search approach with branch and bound to solve the knapsack problem. Everything is fine up to a 1000 items (i get an instant result). However when I run the test with 10,000 Items i get a stack overflow error.

Am I correct in saying that the maximum recursive calls at any one time is equal to the number of items?
I think I know why I'm getting  a stack overflow, here is a code snippet:

```
ArrayList<Item> newChosen = new ArrayList<Item>(chosen);
newChosen.add(nextItem);

//This is where  i believe my code is inefficient.
// there must be a better way of passing a new list
// need to make a new array list due to different 
// recursive instances modifying their lists

calculateKnapsack(new ArrayList<Item>(newChosen), new ArrayList<Item> (toVisit));
calculateKnapsack(new ArrayList<Item>(chosen), new ArrayList<Item>(toVisit));
```

I guess the real question is, what is a better way of recursively passing the list, or an altogether better approach to recursive dfs branch and bound?

Thanks a lot guys.

NOTE: This is for the Discrete Optimisation course on Coursera

Comment: 10,000 recursive calls is quite a lot, anyway. You can either increase the stack size or use a non-recursive approach.

Comment: So doing "calculateKnapsack(new ArrayList<Item>(newChosen)......" is the only of passing in a list into the recursive, it just seems really inefficient to create a new array list per recursive call.

Comment: Well, you can pass a reference to an existing list, of course, but then you should be careful with modifying it(if there are no modifications, there is no need to create a copy).